# Using multicols, introduced by a subsection title, after a section heading leaves a blank page

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titles, multicolumn, blank-page

Many articles on StackExchange show the same problem but none of the solutions works for me. I initialize a `section` environment and then a `multicol` environment, with a subsection header as an argument. Anything you put in the square brackets next to `\begin{multicols}{2}` should be written as a non-multicolumn sentence, meaning it doesn't respect the "boxed" boundaries of the columns, whereas anything before `\end{multicols}` does. I'm using the `multicol` environment for the majority of my report and it always works fine.

I've tried putting the `\section` in the square brackets as well, but I would need a line break `\\` and a multi-line sentence isn't allowed.

The matter is shown in the following pictures.

[image: Blank page left behind the subsection title. The section header is shown.]

[image: Multicol environment compiles well, but in the next page.]

The code compiling the previous pages:

```
\section{Definizione del momento magnetico}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\subsection{L'ipotesi dell'integrale della f.e.m.}]

...texttexttext...
```

Here's the introduction to my document as well. Nothing in there looks like it can cause any problems, but here it is anyways.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Immagini/} }
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Others
\singlespacing
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

% Omit `.0` in equation numbers for non-existent subsections.
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 %
    \thesection
  \else
    \thesubsection
  \fi
  .\arabic{equation}%
}

% Custom command for slanted bars ("parallel")
\newcommand{\slanted}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
\newcommand{\ddd}{\text{d}} % d normale in math mode
```

Comment: do not show only snippets and screenshots. Always make a small but complete example that can be used for a test. (I can't reproduce your problem in a MWE).

Comment: You're missing to show the document class. I tried with `article` and `lipsum` for the text, reproducing the lengths of the various parts and I get no strange page break. Are you perhaps using `[H]` as the float specifier? If so, don't.

Comment: I believe `\section` etc. includes `\par` and `\vskip`, so is definitely not a single line.  You could put it into a `\parbox` or minipage, althugh you will lose the effect of `\@afterheading`.

Comment: I don't know how to answer each comment individually, so here is everything and thanks in advance for your time.
First of all, I couldn't show individual examples, since every time I try to do it again latex compiles everything without the blank page. It's a one-case scenario, as far as I've seen, so I'm pretty sure I'm getting something wrong one way or another.
Secondly, no, I'm not using [H] or any floating specifier at all.
Finally, yes, ```\section``` includes ```\par``` and everything, but it didn't seem to work with ```\subsection```. Definitely going to experiment with that though.